# Query "or" e "and" no Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Preciso fazer esta query no laravel:

```
SELECT * FROM materiais 
        where material like '%caneta%' 
        or localização like '%armario%' 
        or fornecedor like '%kalunga%' 
        and setor = 'secretaria'
        order by item_id asc;
```

Objetivo: Filtrar todas as "canetas" ou todos os "armarios" ou todos os fornecedores "kalunga" que existem **somente** na "secretaria", nos outros setores ele ignora. Fazendo esta busca direto no banco de dados, retorna exatamente o que preciso que retorne.

No laravel, ainda que sem sucesso, o mais próximo que consegui chegar da query acima foi:

```
$teste = Material::where('setor', 'secretaria')
        ->orWhere('material', 'like', '%caneta%')
        ->orWhere('localização', 'like', '%armario%')
        ->orWhere('fornecedor', 'like', '%kalunga%')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->paginate(150);
```

Isto retorna todos os materiais corretamente, mas não somente da secretaria, ele retorna de todos os outros setores também.

Caso alguém conheça uma solução. Obrigado e abraços!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve usar [Parameter Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#parameter-grouping), desta forma:

```
$teste = Material::where('setor', 'secretaria')
                  ->where(function($query) {
                      $query->where('material', 'like', '%caneta%')
                          ->orWhere('localização', 'like', '%armario%')
                          ->orWhere('fornecedor', 'like', '%kalunga%');
                  })
                  ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                  ->paginate(150);
```

Na primeira linha da função você usa `where`, e nas demais `orWhere`. O código acima seria equivalente a:

```
...
WHERE setor = 'secretaria'
AND (
   material LIKE '%caneta%'
   OR
   localização LIKE '%armario%'
   OR
   fornecedor LIKE '%kalunga%'
)
ORDER BY id DESC
...
```

Ou seja, o `setor` deve ser obrigatoriamente `secretaria` **e** pelo menos uma das 3 condições em `material`, `localização` ou `fornecedor` deve ser atendida.

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu! Uma informação adicional. Como é uma busca, vem de um form com um valor pesquisado pelo usuário. Então tive que passar este valor para dentro da função e ficou desta forma: Ex.:

$teste = Material::where('setor', 'secretaria')
                  ->where(function($query) use ($material) {
                      $query->where('material', 'like', '%'.$material.'%');
                  })
                  ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                  ->paginate(150);